# How many positive 4-digit integers are there?

Tags: combinatorics

> How many positive 4-digit integers are there?
>
> Ans= 9*10*10*10=9000

I don't get it, what about the number after 9000.
9000-9999 are still positive 4-digit integers right?

Comment: The reason why the first number in the product is a 9 instead of a 10 is because we don't include the ones that start with a 0 - not because we don't include those starting with a 9.

Comment: The numbers 0-999 are not 4-digit numbers.

Comment: no i mean 9001,9002...9999.

Comment: you are counting numbers from 0-999 as 4-digits no. in your interpretation of 9000.

Comment: lol nvm I get it now. thanks all!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first 999 numbers are only three or fewer digits long; 9999 is the last four digit number. Hence 9000 is the number of up-to-4 digit numbers minus the three-or-fewer digit numbers.

Answer (score 5):

You can do this by determining valid values for each ***position*** or your numbers:

Call the first number the left-most digit. The second, third, and fourth digit appearing to the left of the preceding digit.

The first digit of a four-digit number must be greater than zero. (We have to rule out numbers with fewer than $4$ digits, e.g., we don't want to count $(0)123, (00)29, (0)999$, etc.)

So that leaves $9$ values $(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9)$ that can take the first position. The second, third, and fourth digit can include zero, so there are $10$ possible values, ranging from $0$ to $9$ for each of those positions.

That gives us the total number of 4-digit numbers less than 1000: $$9 \times 10 \times 10\times 10$$

Comment: Could use some more votes +1

Answer (score 1):

HINT:

Numbers $<5$ digits $=10^5-1=9999:\{1,2,\cdots,9998,9999\}$

Numbers  $\le3$ digits $=10^3-1=999:\{1,2,\cdots,998,999\}$

Comment: not what the question wanted

Comment: @AtulGangwar, if you subtract, you will get the value

Comment: that should have been the hint. What you wrote was already known by him

Comment: @AtulGangwar, if he know that, then the question would not have arisen

Comment: @AtulGangwar, have you noticed the other answer?

Comment: @Atul: for someone with a profile that says "please delete me", you sure are active!

Comment: Well i was trolling here, so that i thought you would delete me!

Comment: Zero is also an integer, so number less than 5 digits is 10000 and number less than 4 digits is 1000. Gives the same answer.

Answer (score 0):

We can count all of the positive $4$-digit integers by counting all of the choices for the ones, tens, hundreds, and thousands place. Once this has been done we can use the Multiplication Principle to obtain the number of permutations we seek. The possible values are from the set $S=\{0,1,2,...,8,9\}$. The ones places has $10$ choices, the tens place has $10$ choices, the hundreds place has $10$ choices, and the thousands place has $9$ choices (we do not want to include a leading $0$ since we wouldn't have an actual positive $4$-digit integer). Thus by the Multiplication Princple there are $9\times 10\times 10\times 10=9000$ positive $4$-digit integers.

Answer (score 0):

It is easy if you think about it this way:
Step 1: find the least 4-digit integer--1000
Step 2: find the greatest 4-digit integer--9999
Step 3: follow the rule---
the rule is the last number minus the first number then add one.
so the answer is 9999-1000+1=8999+1=9000

See it is easy.
How can I find the rule:
I test my rule with a small number: for example
how many numbers are there from 10 to 19? 10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19 it is the. so the rule is 19-10+1=10

Comment: This question has a well-accepted answer. You are not contributing anything new. Please refrain from answering such old questions. There are many new unanswered questions